# cmake shared libraries

Tags: c++, loops, cmake

I'm building app with boost.python. I want to make each cpp-module as a single shared library.

I have a list of cpp-files, how to make in cycle different subprojects with name taken from **cpp** file?

For example:

```
set(Script_srcs
    Module1.cpp
    Module2.cpp
    Module3.cpp
)

some_cycle
  add_library( {NAME} SHARED {PATH} )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [foreach](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:foreach) to iterate over your source-files and use a the function [get_filename_component](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:get_filename_component) with NAME_WE to get only the filename, something like:

```
set(Script_srcs Module1.cpp Module2.cpp Module3.cpp )

foreach( f ${Script_srcs} )
    get_filename_component( ff ${f} NAME_WE )
    add_library( ${ff} SHARED ${f} )
endforeach( f )
```

But, instead of deriving library-names from filenames, why not work the other way around? Derive your filenames from the desired module-names and append ".cpp" in the for-loop:

```
set( MyModules Module1 Module2 Module3 ) 
foreach( Mod ${MyModules} )
    add_library( ${Mod} SHARED ${Mod}.cpp )
endforeach( Mod )
```